# Count and range MongoDB

Tags: mongodb

Let´s say I have a bunch of documents in this format;

```
{Person: "X" , Note: 4}
```

What I need to do is to count the total of Person who has the field Note within the range 0 - 50, 51-100, 101-150 and 150 or more

Something like this

```
//range of Note       //total of persons in this range
0-50                   14
51-100                 32
101-150                34
151                    21
```

Answer (score 1):

In MongoDb you have $lt and $gt commands through which you can get less then and greater then values.
Then you can use $count on it  like this->

```
db.table.aggregate(
  [
    {
      $match: {
        Note: {
          $gt: 0, $lt: 50
        }
      }
    },
    {
      $count: "0-50"
    }
  ]
)
```

It will show result like:

```
{ "0-50" : 14 }
```

Comment: And for the other ranges another $match? like :   ...}], [ { $match....     ??

Comment: There are multiple ways,you can use multiple $match or $and inside a  $match...

Comment: "Unrecognized pipeline stage name: '$count'"

Comment: which version you are using?it's avialable in 3.4